# Using nginx as a proxy have some bad affect on SEO?

Tags: seo, google, domains

I have website hosted in ovh france,
I want to use digitalocean los angeles droplet only like nginx as a proxy,
so if someone try whois will see my digitalocean ip,
this can somehow affect bad on seo or give google penalty?

Comment: Where is the site used? In France, in California, or around the world?   How does this affect the speed of the site?

Comment: website is use around the world, this will bad affect on speed i was think this will not affect on page speed so im wrong?

Comment: "so if someone try whois will see my digitalocean ip" this is unclear and/or unrelated. You do not need whois to see IP addresses, just resolving the name in the DNS is enough. I agree with Stephen, the main issue will be more about speed, so why do you want such setup? Why a proxy on one continent and the real server on another? what is the goal?